# How do you get the exact text and not the text value of in a cell when using the LEFT/RIGHT functions in Excel?

Tags: excel

I am viewing the the Citi bike trip data on an Excel spreadsheet and I am using the "RIGHT" function to gather the text from the four digits to the right of the D column, which should be in a four-digit time format ("00:00").  Upon typing the function =RIGHT(D2,4), I get the last digits of the elapsed time between the start times in column C to the end times in Column D.  I would like the exact text to be displayed.

I tried typing in the function as =RIGHT(TEXT(D2,"00:00")4) hoping it would give me the exact times.

Comment: Time is a decimal formatted to look like time.  `=MOD(D2,1)` will isolate the decimal.  Then format the cell to show the time.